# Custom Invoice Table

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to edit our Shopify 'New Order Notification' email and create a custom table to organize the information a bit better.

It should look like this on desktop, but I'd like to have the totals lined up with the 'line price' column.

[image]

On mobile, it looks like this the totals aren't aligned and the 'totals' table doesn't have a 100% width.

[image]

I know I obviously need to add mobile queries, which I tried & removed, I just got tired of trying & brought my issue here.

What styles or edits should I make to make both tables 100% on desktop & mobile, and how do I align the totals with the last column of the top table?

Here's my CSS:

```
/* general styles */

.main-container {
    width: 80%;     
}   

table, tr, td, th {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table {     
    width: 100%;
}

/* table-1-items styles */


.table-1-headers {
    background-color: #00a850;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.table-1-headers td {
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.left-justify {
    text-align: left;   
}

.center-justify  {
    text-align: center; 
}

.header-item {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.item-image,
.item-title,
.item-sku,
.item-price,
.item-qty,
.total-line-price,
.header-item-price,
.header-qty,
.header-line-price {
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.spacer {
    height: 15px;
}

/* table-2-totals styles */

.table-2-totals {
    border-top: 2px solid black;
}

.totals-row-1 {
    padding-top: 15px;  
}

.order-instructions {
    font-weight: bold;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: 10px 30px 5px 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.order-instructions span {
    background-color: yellow;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.totals-header {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: right;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.totals {
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 22px !important;
    min-width:101px !important;
}

.subtotal-header,
.subtotal-input {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<p>Hello {{ shop_name }},</p>

<p>{% if customer.name %}<b>{{ customer.name }}</b>{% else %}Someone{% endif %} placed a new order with your store, {{ date | date: "%b %d %I:%M%p" }}:</p>

<div class="main-container">
<table class="table-1-items">

    <tr class="table-1-headers" >
        <td colspan="2" class="header-item left-justify" >Item</td>
        <td class="header-sku left-justify">SKU</td>
        <td class="header-item-price center-justify">Item Price</td>
        <td class="header-qty center-justify">Qty</td>
        <td class="header-line-price center-justify">Line Price</td>
    </tr>
    {% for line in line_items %} 
    <tr class="item-line"> 
        <td class="item-image center-justify"><img src="{{ line | img_url: 'thumb' }}" alt="Item Image" /></td>
        <td class="item-title left-justify">{{ line.title }}</td>
        <td class="item-sku left-justify">{{ line.sku | lowcase }}</td>
        <td class="item-price center-justify">{{ line.price | money }}</td>
        <td class="item-qty center-justify">{{ line.quantity }}</td>
        <td class="total-line-price center-justify">{{ line.line_price | money }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    <tr class="spacer"></tr>
</table>

<table class="table-2-totals">
    <tr class="totals-row-1">
        <td rowspan="7" class="order-instructions">ORDER NOTE/SPECIAL INSTRUCTIONS<br><span>{{ note }}</span></td>
        <td class="totals-header subtotal-header">Subtotal:</td>
        <td class="totals subtotal-input">{{ subtotal_price | money }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="totals-header">Tax:</td>
        <td class="totals">{{ total_tax | money }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="totals-header">Rate:</td>
        <td class="totals">{{ tax_line.rate }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="totals-header">Discounts:</td>
        <td class="totals">{{ discounts_amount | money }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="totals-header">Shipping:</td>
        <td class="totals">{{ shipping_price | money }}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="totals-header">Total:</td>
        <td class="totals">{{ total_price | money }}</td>
    </tr>                        
</table>

</div>

<br>
<br>
<a href="https://{{ shop.permanent_domain }}/admin/orders/{{ id }}">View order {{order_name}} </a>
<br>

{% if fulfillment_aborted %}
<p>The above order was not automatically fulfilled because it was flagged as suspicious.</p>{% endif %}
<br>

{% if has_high_risks? %}<p><b>Security check:</b></p>
<p>This order has a risk of being fraudulent. Review the order in your store's admin and contact the customer to verify their information.</p>
{% endif %}
<br>

<p><b>Customer Email: </b>{{ email }}</p>
<p><b>Customer Company: </b>{{ billing_address.company }}</p>

<br>
<p><b>Payment processing method:</b></p>
<p>{{ gateway }}</p>
<br>

{% if requires_shipping and shipping_address %}
<p><b>Delivery method:</b></p>
{% for shipping_method in shipping_methods %}<p>{{ shipping_method.title }}</p>{% endfor %}

<br>
<p><b>Shipping address:</b></p>
<p>{{ shipping_address.name }}</p>
<p>{{ shipping_address.street }}</p>
<p>{{ shipping_address.city }}, {{ shipping_address.province }}  {{ shipping_address.zip }}</p>
<p>{{ shipping_address.country }}</p>
<p>{{ shipping_address.phone }}{% endif %}</p>
<br>

{% if shopify_shipping_enabled %}
<p>Save time and money by <a href="{{ fulfillment_url }}">fulfilling with Shopify Shipping</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if tables have no defined height they will keep getting smaller until they can no longer get any smaller, then they stop where they are.

Add this to your CSS

```
table {
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

All I'm doing there is telling the tables to be 100% wide, to a maximum of 800px, and a minimum of 500px. (adjust as required)

When you've added this you'll also want to remove the right paddding on the totals for MOBILES

```
.totals {
  padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

You also have a style called .main-container which has a max width of 80%... you need to replace that with

```
.main-container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What would be the best media query to use? @media and screen (max-width: 500px) {} ?

Comment: Yes that would be fine, I'm not sure puttng @media in emails in a great idea... they are supported by some email clients.. try to remove that right padding altogether, I'm not sure why its there anyway...

Comment: I did as you instructed... added max-width, min-width, & width to my css. I also removed the padding. The table displays correctly on desktop now, but when viewed on a mobile, the 2nd table still shows as in the image above except shorter in width.

Comment: I've amended my answer above.

Comment: Changing that .main-container width fixed the problem. Thank you for your help!